# Line bisecting the angle between the coordinate curves?

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that the lines that at each point bisect the angles between the coordinate lines are given by the differential equations $$\sqrt{E}\,du \pm \sqrt{G}\,dv = 0$$

I calculated the angle between the coordinate curves: $cos\varphi=\frac{F}{\sqrt{EG}}$.

Next, I tried to substitute a half angle into the formula for the angle between the curves and prove the original statement, but the result does not match.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **HINT**: Compare the angles between such a curve and each of the coordinate curves. In particular, what is the tangent vector to a curve satisfying this differential equation?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the unit vector along u direction $\frac{1}{\sqrt{E}}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and the unit vector along v direction $\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$. Now the tangent vector of the solution curve is $v=\sqrt{G}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\pm \sqrt{E}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$. You will get the same projection of $v$ onto the two directions $\sqrt{EG}\pm F$.

Comment: Thank you! This helped to solve.

Comment: You are welcome.